# Can visiting Pirate Bay itself give you malware?

Tags: malware, macos, torrent, drive-by-download

So I have a MacBook running High Sierra latest version and I decided to go to the Pirate Bay search engine  for the first time just for seeing how it looks and just some research. So I searched for Adobe photoshop for Mac and it showed up I clicked to download and it redirected me to a scam website with loud beep noises saying that I have a virus, I know this kind of scam. So I ignored it. Then when I clicked download again it didn't download a torrent file but a dmg file called "Easy Setup.dmg" I didn't run it because I knew again it will just install malware on my Mac.

But now I feel paranoid, that I could have got malware by just visiting the pirate bay search engine because I think javascript allows that. Correct me if I am wrong.

PS. I have heard that MacOS is sandboxed and prevents malware from reaching the heart of the machine but does it protect against remote access and key loggers?

Comment: I know this question is a little bit different, but what computer you are using or what website you are visiting doesn't really matter. The answer is still "yes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*TL;DR* **YES**,  visiting *any* site can in principle give you malware.

Even legitimate sites with a proven history of security might be at risk because, for example, they might be sporting **ads**, and those ads aren't in the site's control, but come from a third party that might have been compromised, or might have poor security and not be aware of the fact that [what was supplied as an "advertising banner" by an *apparently* legitimate advertiser, and pulled to thousands of sites for their visitors to see, was actually **malware**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvertising).

> But now I feel paranoid, that I could have got malware by just visiting the pirate bay search engine because I think javascript allows that. Correct me if I am wrong.

It depends on the browser (you can browse the CVE repository for any specific browser; this is the map for [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.cvedetails.com/product/3264/Mozilla-Firefox.html?vendor_id=452)). Which is why you want to always have it updated and with the security patches installed. Windows is a bit more vulnerable due to the support for WSH, which supplies an additional attack vector. But there are lots of such vectors; for example, again with Firefox (but don't think the other browser are safer), in 2016 there was [WebGL](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2016-1935/) on Linux systems too:

```
Confidentiality Impact     Complete (There is total information disclosure,
                            resulting in all system files being revealed.)
Integrity Impact           Complete (There is a total compromise of system integrity. 
                            There is a complete loss of system protection, resulting 
                            in the entire system being compromised.)
Access Complexity          Medium (The access conditions are somewhat specialized. 
                           Some preconditions must be satistified to exploit)
```

Usual tricks include:

- downloading some script that will then try to infect other websites you might be visiting,
- popping up some ads when you least expect them,
- cheat other websites by making you unwittingly generate traffic,
- directly exploiting your machine as part of a "botnet" for:

  - running DDoSes,
  - mining bitcoins,
  - sending spam,
  - bruteforcing other sites,
  - running distributed operations to circumvent some services' request limit from a single IP or subnet

**Usually** these tricks aren't persistent if the browser is properly hardened, and when you close the browser, they halt. Though they *will* try to persist themselves, so if your armor has a chink they can exploit...

And, of course, nothing can help you if you willingly download something and then consent to have it running.

Regarding "cracks", consider that when running one, you're basically trusting that someone you don't know went to all the trouble of researching, writing and distributing the crack, breaking the law and risking fines or even jail time, *just to do you a favor - for free*. And also that the cracked program will keep working correctly and without unwanted side effects for the reasonable future. From a purely rational and non-moral point of view, both of these assumptions looks quite unbalanced towards the *ass* part, and conducive to poor security.

> PS. I have heard that MacOS is sandboxed and prevents malware from reaching the heart of the machine but does it protect against remote access and key loggers?

The 'sandboxing' your refer to is probably privilege separation. This means that whatever you do *as an ordinary user* cannot propagate outside your user's account "sandbox". The problem is that *you* work inside that sandbox, so you're still vulnerable to malware even if the other users of the same machine aren't. For this reason some users have *two* accounts, one for browsing and one for work. Not a perfect protection, but better than none, at the expense of some nuisance when you switch from the one to the other.

Remote access usually requires higher privileges, so you're almost certainly protected from *that*.

For the rest, you need an updated antivirus; and just to be sure, an encrypted backup of your data, kept current and tested every now and then, somewhere different than where your PC is. Sometimes you defend against hackers only to be burgled out of your data.

Answer (score 2):

One issue that I have heard of about it; The website was (and maybe still is) known to use scripts to use your computer recources for mining cryptocurrencies. This makes your computer slow or mayeb unresponsive.

Comment: TPB did that? I was not aware of that.